# xslt 1.0 How to format output based on a conditional test

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm trying to read an xml file that has a series of sub-nodes. Based on the value of one of the subnodes (within a set), I want that particular output to be bolded.

Here is the xml example:

```
<documentationOf>
  <event>
    <effectiveTime>
      <low value="9/4/2013" />
    </effectiveTime>
  </event>
</documentationOf>
<entry>
  <substanceAdministration>
    <text>
      <reference value="">
      </reference>
    </text>
    <effectiveTime>
      <low value="5/13/2013 12:00:00 AM" />
      <high value="UNK" />
    </effectiveTime>
    <consumable>
      <manufacturedProduct>
        <manufactueredMaterial>
          <code code="" displayName="Product 1">
          </code>
        </manufacturedMaterial>
      </manufacturedProduct>
    </consumable>
  </substanceAdministration>
</entry>
<entry>
  <substanceAdministration>
    <text>
      <reference value="">
      </reference>
    </text>
    <effectiveTime>
      <low value="9/4/2013 12:00:00 AM" />
      <high value="UNK" />
    </effectiveTime>
    <consumable>
      <manufacturedProduct>
        <manufactueredMaterial>
          <code code="" displayName="Product 2">
          </code>
        </manufacturedMaterial>
      </manufacturedProduct>
    </consumable>
  </substanceAdministration>
</entry>
<entry>
  <substanceAdministration>
    <text>
      <reference value="">
      </reference>
    </text>
    <effectiveTime>
      <low value="5/13/2013 12:00:00 AM" />
      <high value="UNK" />
    </effectiveTime>
    <consumable>
      <manufacturedProduct>
        <manufactueredMaterial>
          <code code="" displayName="Product 3">
          </code>
        </manufacturedMaterial>
      </manufacturedProduct>
    </consumable>
  </substanceAdministration>
</entry>
```

I want the code/@displayName to appear (which I can do a for-each and get that to work) but if the effectiveTime/low/@value is today's date (which is in the documentationOf/event/effectivetime/low/@value), then I want it to be in bold:

```
Product 1
<b>Product 2</b>
Product 3
```

Here is the XSL snipped for this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="entry">
  <xsl:value-of select="substanceAdministration/consumable/manufacturedProduct/manufacturedMaterial/code/@displayName" />
  <br />
</xsl:for-each>
```

I realize I should probably be doing this with its own template, but I didn't write the xsl msyelf and in the interests of time, I am making do with what's there. I am however, trying to redo it in parallel with templates (the right way) but will still need to know the best way to check that effectiveTime/low/@value to make the entry bold in the output.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: XSLT 1.0 doesn't have any date functions. That means you would need to use an extension. Are you able to use something like EXSLT with your XSL processor?

Comment: Not that I know of. I can ask about that. So what you're saying is that I can't compare that low/@value with Date or Now()?

Comment: Which XSLT processor are you using?

Comment: actually.. I have another node (will update the example) that has the date that I want to compare it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the process I would use.

First create a global variable with your date for today.

```
<xsl:variable name="today" select="//documentationOf/event/effectiveTime/low/@value"/>
```

Then you can update your `for-each` to include a call to a template and a `span` to add your bold styling to.

```
<xsl:for-each select="entry">
  <xsl:variable name="IsToday">
    <xsl:call-template name="compareToday">
      <xsl:with-param name="date" select="substanceAdministration/effectiveTime/low/@value"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:variable>
  <span>
    <xsl:if test="$IsToday = 'true'">
      <xsl:attribute name="style">
        <xsl:text>font-weight:bold;</xsl:text>
      </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="substanceAdministration/consumable/manufacturedProduct/manufacturedMaterial/code/@displayName" />
  </span>
  <br />
</xsl:for-each>
```

And then the `compareToday` named template to compare your two dates.

```
<xsl:template name="compareToday">
  <xsl:param name="date"/>
  <xsl:if test="substring($date,0,(string-length($date) - 11)) = $today">
    <xsl:text>true</xsl:text>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

You will notice that in the above template I had to take a substring of the date so that it matches the format of the today date variable. If the format varies any from those two you would need to update this template to convert them both to the same format before you could compare them.

After running this it produces this output.

```
<span>Product 1</span><br/>
<span style="font-weight:bold;">Product 2</span><br/>
<span>Product 3</span><br/>
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you. I can still use this when I do things correctly with templates as well it looks like.

Answer (score 0):

So you need to check the date of each `entry` against the date extracted from its `documentationOf` sibling:

```
<xsl:for-each select="entry">
  <xsl:variable name="displayName" select="substanceAdministration/consumable/manufacturedProduct/manufacturedMaterial/code/@displayName" />
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="starts-with(substanceAdministration/effectiveTime/low/@value,
                                ../documentationOf/event/effectiveTime/low/@value)">
      <b><xsl:value-of select="$displayName" /></b>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select="$displayName" />
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
  <br />
</xsl:for-each>
```

This assumes that the `documentationOf` and its corresponding `event`s are grouped under a common parent element and there's only one `documentationOf` sibling with each group of `event` elements (if there's more than one then only the effectiveTime of the *first* one will be used).